# Download PDF using ASIHTTPRequest, simulator is OK, but the device gets ASIHTTPRequest error

Tags: ios, ipad, error-handling, download, asihttprequest

I've got a strange issue. Using `ASIHTTPRequest` to realize the PDF download function, it works well in my iPad simulator (iOS 7.0 & 7.1), but I got the following error when running in a device (iPad iOS 7.0.4).

```
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=1 "A connection failure occurred" UserInfo=0x180326a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x18032130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 2.)", NSLocalizedDescription=A connection failure occurred}
```

I've tried to clean my project/restart Xcode/set `[request setTimeOutSeconds:60]`, but none of them work.

Wish anyone could give me some suggestions. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Can you put the crash log here, also increase the time out to larger value and see.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really rely on simulator for some of the stuff like this. 
Try adding something like this to see the actual error description in a more human-understandable way:

```
-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{ 

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[request.error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [alertView show];
}
```

Which will tell you that you're getting a time out. To fix that, try adding this to your code:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
request.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
```

And that should fix it.

[P.S. Similar questions have been asked before.]

Comment: Actually, I've searched this question and found the solution you mentioned above.But it really doesn't work. Or else, I wouldn't ask again. In simulator it works well, but not in device. Strange...

Comment: Added a line to the answer. Simulator isn't always reliable. What does that suggested `UIAlertView` return? And do you try repeating this more than once in a row on the device?

Comment: UIAlertView says,"A connection failure occurred". And yes, I've added the line every place I used ASIHTTPRequest, but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Sorry, the second question in my previous comment seems a bit confusing. I meant to try running the app/downloading process several times to see if it keeps happening every time or once or ... .

Comment: Oh, yes, I tried many times and every time it shows the same error.